# MySQL select and update multiple rows from same table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-update, mysql-error-1093

Generally I want to select rows from `orders` table in my database, that were created after some date, and then update `office_id` field for all of selected rows to the specific value `12`.
My MySQL version is 5.5.43.
At firs I was trying to put it in one SQL statement like so:

```
UPDATE `order`
SET office_id = 12
WHERE id IN (  
  SELECT id
  FROM  `order` 
  WHERE created_at >= DATE_FORMAT( '2014-07-02 00:00:00', '%Y.%m.%d 00:00:00' ) 
);
```

And I was getting error: `#1093 - You can't specify target table 'order' for update in FROM clause`.

Next I tried to do this with `SELECT .. FOR UPDATE` statment like so:

```
START TRANSACTION;

SELECT id
FROM  `order` 
WHERE created_at >= DATE_FORMAT( '2014-07-02 00:00:00', '%Y.%m.%d 00:00:00' ) 
FOR UPDATE;

UPDATE `order`
SET office_id = 12
WHERE id IN ( id );

COMMIT;
```

Which worked, but if `SELECT .. FOR UPDATE` statement returns no rows, then `office_id = 12` would be applied to all rows in `orders` table, which I defenetely don't want.

I'm looking for help in modification 1st or 2nd solution for propper working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's much simpler than you're making it. You can apply a WHERE clause directly to an [UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html) statement.

```
UPDATE `order`
    SET office_id = 12
    WHERE created_at >= DATE_FORMAT( '2014-07-02 00:00:00', '%Y.%m.%d 00:00:00' );
```

Comment: Presumably, `id` is unique in `order`, in which case this should work. However, the two queries are not necessary equivalent.  You are making some assumptions about the data structure.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes, `id` is unique. This is the best solution in this particular situation.

Answer (score 2):

If `id` can be duplicated in `order`, then you can express the query using a `join`:

```
UPDATE `order` o JOIN
       (SELECT distinct o.id
        FROM  `order` o
        WHERE created_at >= DATE_FORMAT( '2014-07-02 00:00:00', '%Y.%m.%d 00:00:00' 
       ) oo
       ON o.id = oo.id
    SET o.office_id = 12;
```

Comment: Thanks for comment. I uesd your solution in slightly different situation and it worked perfectly with `JOIN`